# I cannot set IIS authentication programatically using c#

Tags: c#, iis-7

I'm trying to turn of Anonymous authentication on a site using c#

This code throws exception written at bottom i searched everywhere i cant find answer how to solve it:

```
using (ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager())
{
    Configuration configapp = serverManager.GetApplicationHostConfiguration();
    ConfigurationSection anonymousAuthenticationSection = configapp.GetSection("system.webServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication", Site1);
    anonymousAuthenticationSection["enabled"] = false;

    serverManager.CommitChanges();
}
```

The exception:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Filename: \\?\C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config
Error: Unrecognized configuration path 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Site1'
   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.Interop.AppHostWritableAdminManager.GetAdminSection(String bstrSectionName, String bstrSectionPath)
   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.Configuration.GetSectionInternal(ConfigurationSection section, String sectionPath, String locationPath)
   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.Configuration.GetSection(String sectionPath, String locationPath)
   at FlowSuiteWebConfigurator.label.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Administrator\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Projectname\Projectname\Form1.cs:line 264
```

Can someone guide me how to fix this?

Comment: Seeing as you have C# tagged, I'm guessing this is ASP.NET. If you are wanting to deny any users that aren't authenticated, you would be better off doing it in the web.config of your actual website. This should deny unauthorized users from accessing your site. <system.web><authorization><deny users="?"/></authorization></system.web>

Comment: I'm actually using c# as IIS web configurator form. and i want first to disable anon login programaticaly and then apply only "windows authentification"

Answer (score 2):

A bit late maybe (1 year and a half after...), but the problem seems to be in your location definition (2nd parameter of configapp.GetSection): the exception said `Error: Unrecognized configuration path 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Site1'`

Tested locally on my machine, I have no exception with a valid location name like `Default Web Site/MyCustomPortal`.

Note: the reference added is `Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll` under `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\` , and those lines of code look into the file `applicationHost.config` located in `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config`